# Session changed at each request in Java Servlet 3.0

Tags: java, session, servlets, sessionid, jsessionid

We use the `geronimo-servlet 3.0` and `Tomcat 8` to run a servlet which will use the session as below

```
@Service
public class SessionServiceImpl implements SessionService
{
    @Autowired(required = false)
    private HttpServletRequest  request;
    private HttpSession         session = null;

    @Override
    public void setUser(User user)
    {
        session = request.getSession();
        if (session != null)
        {
            session.setAttribute(SessionAttribute.user.name(), user);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setData(String data)
    {
        session = request.getSession();
        if (session != null)
        {
            session.setAttribute(SessionAttribute.data.name(), data);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public HttpSession getSession()
    {
        session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("TimeoutBased", System.currentTimeMillis());
        return session;
    }
}
```

In other services, AuthService, for example, call the sessionService as below

```
public class AuthServiceImpl extends CustomizedServlet implements AuthService
{
    @Autowired
    private SessionService              sessionService;

    @Override
    public BaseModel login(BaseModel user) {
        ...
        sessionService.setUser(userEntity);
        ...
        sessionService.setData(data);
    }
}
```

CustomizedServlet is a `com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet` for GWT. And the login method is for the web client to login. This is all working normally.

Sometimes, however, for the unknown reason, the session changed at each request send from the web client open by Google Chrome.

Moreover, in debug mode, I saw the session Id keeping changed in one request as below figures show.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The first request response as below

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=53144E2C46D6DF7C5986D56F01A6961E; Path=/ABC/; HttpOnly
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Disposition: attachment
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1909
Date: Tue, 07 Mar 2017 01:42:13 GMT
```

Another servlet for comet is the second request and there is no jsessionid in the request

```
GET /ABC/CometServlet?qndOeINh HTTP/1.1
Host: web.test.abc.com:8080
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-javascript;
Accept: */*
Referer: http://web.test.abc.com:8080/ABC/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: zh-TW,zh;q=0.8,ja;q=0.6
Cookie: username=%7B%22state%22%3A%22s%3Aadmin%22%7D;
```

After all, if I clear **the site data** of chrome, it keeps working normally. Not yet to figure out the root cause of this situation. Do anyone have some experience or any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this could help, but I was facing a session problem too. The JSESSIONID was changing it's value at each request. This was simply caused by a JSF tag:

```
<h:link outcome="${loguinBean.logOut()}" value="LogOut" />
```

For some reason, when I succesfully logged in and refreshed the page, the session would keep getting lost. After I removed that tag and replaced it with `<h:commandLink>` inside a `<h:form>`, everything worked fine.